# Turning cards (memory)

Tags: javascript, php

I'm doing a memory and got a problem when turning cards. After turning two cards, when I turn a third one, I want the 2 previous cards to be turned again, but for some reason sometimes it works and sometimes only the first of the two cards turned turns. Any idea why this is happening?

JAVASCRIPT (where I think there's the problem):

```
var cartas = [];
var cartasGiradas = [];
var parejas= 0;
function cambiar_clase(){
   cartasGiradas = document.getElementsByClassName("flip-container clicked");
   if(cartasGiradas.length==2){
      for (var i = 0; i <= cartasGiradas.length; i++) {
         cartasGiradas[i].className="flip-container";
         this.classList.add("clicked");}
      }else if(cartasGiradas.length < 2){
         this.classList.add("clicked");
      }
   }
function inicializar(){
   cartas = document.getElementsByClassName("flip-container");
   for(var i = 0; i < cartas.length; i++){
      document.getElementById("a_girar"+i).addEventListener( 'click', cambiar_clase());
   }
}
```

The HTML source:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript_memory.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css_memory.css">
    <title>MEMORY GUERRA</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body onload="inicializar()">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class='color_fondo'>
          <div class='flip-container' id='a_girar0'>
            <div class='flipper'>
              <div class='front'>
                <img src='tras_carta.jpg' class='fotos'>
              </div>
              <div class='back'>
                <img src='cartas/animal_15.jpg' class='fotos'>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class='color_fondo'>
          <div class='flip-container' id='a_girar1'>
            <div class='flipper'>
              <div class='front'>
                <img src='tras_carta.jpg' class='fotos'>
              </div>
              <div class='back'>
                <img src='cartas/animal_14.jpg' class='fotos'>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hope somebody can help and sorry if my english is bad, goodbye!

Comment: can you narrow down your problem? This is too much code, too much logic that we would have to think into.

Comment: Okey, everything appart from the js is in case it helps to understand my problem.

Comment: please show the actual resulting html (only the relevant parts) instead of the php, since that doesn't seem to be involved. (you can also remove [most of the] the css)

Comment: and where is `inicializar()` called?

Comment: the resulting html (the html-source) would be needed..

Comment: It is called at the body tag with : onload="inicializar()".

Comment: The less-than-equal in `for (var i = 0; i <= cartasGiradas.length; i++)` looks wrong, but I'm not sure if it is. Do you intentionally iterate over `0, 1, 2`?

Comment: added html source code for the first two cards, the real one it's the same but with more <tr><td>.  I also think there's something worng but don't know where/why.

Comment: The less-than-equal was just to try out something in case it worked.